# R Shiny: Read CSV from webpage, incomplete final line found by readTableHeader

Tags: r, shiny

I have an issue that I can't seem to find a solution to. I am reading a CSV from a URL on the web which goes somewhat like this (the real one has 4 more columns):

> ### Sample Data from
>    the CSV
>
> Date -------------------------- Close
>   2017-10-23 ----------------- 156.17
>   2017-10-20 ----------------- 156.16
>   2017-10-19 ----------------- 155.98
>   2017-10-18 ----------------- 159.76
>   2017-10-17 ----------------- 160.47
>   2017-10-16 ----------------- 159.88
>   2017-10-13 ----------------- 156.99
>   2017-10-12 ----------------- 156
>   2017-10-11 ----------------- 156.55

The CSV file goes on like this (each day having a record) back till somewhere near 1980. In R Shiny, I use the plot command like this...

```
stockData <- read.csv(url("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB/data.json?api_key=xTLatSPBnz751sCMECza"), header=T, sep=",")
```

...and then continue with this code:

```
plot(stockData$Date, stockData$Close, main="", type="l", las="1", 
      xlab="Date", ylab="Share Price", panel.first = grid())
      points(x=stockData$Date, y=stockData$Close, col='#f44242', type='l', lwd=2)
      grid (10,10, lty = 6, col = "lightgray")
```

...I get these errors:

```
Warning in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB/data.json?api_key=xTLatSPBnz751sCMECza'
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values
```

I don't know which errors are related so if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, that would be awesome. Is it something about the file being to big, and how can I test that? Or is it completely unrelated to this? ***(Note: I downloaded the CSV and linked to the same (big) file and it worked)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that you are reading is a `json` which needs to be parsed and then converted to a `dataframe`. Please use the below code for the same:

```
library(jsonlite)

df <- fromJSON("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB/data.json?api_key=xTLatSPBnz751sCMECza", flatten = T)

stockData <- data.frame(df$dataset_data$data)

names(stockData) <- df$dataset_data$column_names

stockData$Close <- as.numeric(stockData$Close)

plot(stockData$Date, stockData$Close, main="", type="l", las="1", 
     xlab="Date", ylab="Share Price")
points(x=stockData$Date, y=stockData$Close, col='#f44242', type='l', lwd=2)
grid (10,10, lty = 6, col = "lightgray")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I just didn't realize it was a JSON file. Now I see it in the URL. You made my day!